# Nested Object Loop in JS

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I'm trying to add a series of values to a nested object, having some trouble with the loop in the following code. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
let settings = {};

function write(id, values) {
    if(!settings[id]) settings[id] = {};
    for(var x = 0; x < Object.keys(values).length; x ++) {
        settings[id][values[x]] = values[values[x]];
    }
}

//example
write('example', {'prop1': 5, 'prop2': 10});
```

Comment: What is the expected output? `values[x]` is similar to values[0], `values` is an object. This will fail if `values` object dont have key `0`

Comment: It would be better if you could publish the original object and the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values` is an object. Accessing `values[x]` will return undefined.

You have to access it with the correct keys in that object as below.

```js
let settings = {};

function write(id, values) {
  if (!settings[id]) settings[id] = {};
  const keys = Object.keys(values);
  for (var x = 0; x < keys.length; x++) {
    settings[id][keys[x]] = values[keys[x]];
  }
  console.log(settings)
}

//example
write('example', { 'prop1': 5, 'prop2': 10 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to index the object `values` with `x`, which is a number. To loop through the keys of your object you can use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop:

```js
function write(id, values) {
    if(!settings[id]) settings[id] = {};
    for(const key in values) {
        settings[id][key] = values[key];
    }
}
```

---

Another approach would be to use object destructuring:

```js
function write(id, values) {
    settings[id] = { ...(settings[id] || {}), ...values };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to keep the Object.keys(values) return in another variable and use it to assign value in setting like this

```
function write(id, values) {
    if(!settings[id]) settings[id] = {};
    const key = Object.keys(values) 
    for(var x = 0; x < key.length; x ++) {
        settings[id][key[x]] = values[key[x]];
    }
}
```